# Float point to display hexadecimal x86-64 nasm linux

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

Trying to convert float to hexadecimal in nasm

Comment: For the definitions of variables in NASM take a look in the [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.1). The main question is unclear. Do you want just to see the hexadecimal representation of the DWORD/QWORD  or do you want to convert them to a hexadecimal number e.g 165.5 = A5.8?

Comment: @rkhb "Write a routine that will display each of these numbers as hexadecimal digits using the
internal representation of FP on the machine." Im guessing that i need to convert them

Comment: @rkhb not really sure what you mean by just see them? According to the nasm link my defintions should be correctly right?

Comment: The single precision floating point number `SA: dd 500.312` will be stored as a DWORD value which can be written (represented) hexadecimal as 43FA27F0h. Converting the number from decimal notation 500.312 to hexadecimal notation: 01F4.4FE0h. [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation): 5.00312d * 10d^2 = 1.F44FE0h * 10h^2. BTW: Your definitions are correct.

Comment: The FPU internal represents the number the same way as it is stored by NASM. I guess you have just to perform the first alternative (display the stored value hexadecimal).

Comment: @rkhb oh really . Now that i understand how its stored, how would I display the hexadecimal. Im looking in the nasm link you pointed to me and I cannot find any specific syntax in order to display the hex values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to convert a DWORD (single precision floating point number) to hexadecimal**

The hexadecimal notation is just a simplification of the binary notation. Four bits at a time form one hexadecimal digit.

With

```
SA: dd 500.312
```

NASM converts the decimal number 500.312 into the internal format "DWORD" - a bunch of 32 bits:

```
01000011111110100010011111110000
```

Group them to 4-bit groups (nibbles) and convert every group to decimal:

```
0100 0011 1111 1010 0010 0111 1111 0000
   4    3   15   10    2    7   15    0
```

The easiest way to get hexadecimal digits is a lookup table. A string is an appropriate way to form an array of 16 hexadecimal characters:

```
hex db "0123456789ABCDEF"
```

Interprete the numbers of each nibble as index of the array  (`[hex+index]`) and store it in a string to be outputted.

A challenge is to isolate the nibbles from left to right. You can us the `ROL,4` instruction, mov the result to another register and isolate the nibble with `AND 0x0F`. Another way is to use `SHLD`. When you have isolated the nibble you have also the index of the hex array.

Example:

```
BITS 64
DEFAULT rel
GLOBAL _start

SECTION .data
    SA dd 500.312               ; Single floating point number
    hex db "0123456789ABCDEF"   ; Array of 16 characters
    lf db 10                    ; New line

SECTION .bss
    outstr resb 16              ; Array of 16 unitialized bytes

SECTION .text

DWORD_to_hex:                   ; ARG: EAX: DWORD value, ESI: Pointer to an array of at least 8 bytes
    xor esi, esi                ; RSI = 0 (access to ESI clears the upper DWORD of RSI)
    mov ecx, 8                  ; RCX = 8
    .LL3:
    xor sil, sil                ; Clear lowest byte of RSI
    shld esi, eax, 4            ; Copy 4 leftmost bits from EAX to ESI
    shl eax, 4                  ; Shift EAX accordingly
    mov dl, [hex + esi]         ; Get a hexadecimal character
    mov [edi], dl               ; Store the character
    add edi, 1                  ; Increment the pointer to outstr
    loop .LL3                   ; Loop RCX times

    ret

_start:                         ; Entry point - here starts the program

    mov eax, [SA]               ; Single floating point number coded as DWORD
    mov rdi, outstr             ; OFFSET outstr
    call DWORD_to_hex

    ; Show hex (8 characters)
    mov eax, 1                  ; SYS_WRITE
    mov edi, 1                  ; STDOUT
    mov rsi, outstr             ; Message address
    mov edx, 8                  ; Number of bytes to display
    syscall                     ; Call Linux

    ; New line
    mov eax, 1                  ; SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, 1                  ; STDOUT
    mov rsi, lf                 ; Message address
    mov edx, 1                  ; Number of bytes to display
    syscall                     ; Call Linux

    ; Exit (0)
    mov eax, 60                 ; SYS_EXIT
    mov edi, 0                  ; Exitcode
    syscall                     ; Call Linux / no return
```

Adjust these steps to get the hexadecimal representation of a QWORD (64 bits) which represents a double precision flosting point number.